# php foreach help

Tags: php, loops

I have a dataset with 4 rows. I am using 2 foreach loops to get my data out. The outer foreach needs to loop once and I need the inner loop to loop 4x. Is there a way to do this or do I need to split the array?

```
  foreach($reports as $key=>$val)
  {
      if($val['rpt_type'] == 'Sooa')
      {
        foreach($val as $foo)
        {
          echo $foo['name'];
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: you might want to add some code to your question, it's very unclear what's going on

Comment: ok, so what's the problem with this code?

Comment: The outer loop loops more than once. I need it to loop only once

Comment: :) So break out at the end of the first loop, right?

Comment: well, what other options are there?

Comment: Cletus suggested range(). Yes, break does work however, I have a question. If it breaks out of the first loop, will the break affect the inner loop? The inner loop will need 0:M iterations.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want the break stmt to affect the inner loop. If I have say 20 data to loop in the inner, they need to complete before the break hits.

Comment: So put the break where it belongs. ffs!

Comment: Could you please show an example of the data your using for this? If $val['rpt_type'] == 'Sooa', how can $val['rpt_type']['name'] exists?

Comment: Well, there is sensitive data in this. It is a customer's db. There are SSNs and DOBs in there. You're right, sooa was where I deleted a ssn

Comment: if you can invision a piece of paper as a report. On the inside of that paper would be other rows of data. That is what I need. Because there are 4 rows of data in this particular report, I am getting 4 pieces of paper. That isn't what I need. There will sometimes be more than 4 rows, it just depends what is coming out of the data.

Comment: silentghost... your break statement doesn't work. the inner loop stops on the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure about how your data structure looks. To me, to be able to utilize a "rpt_type", it would have to look something like this:

```
$reports = array(
    0 => array(
        'rpt_type' => '...',
        ...
        'rows' => array(
            'name' => '...',
            ...
        ),
    ),
    1 => ...
);
```

You could then iterate over it with:

```
foreach($reports as $report) {
    if($report['rpt_type'] == 'Sooa') {
        foreach($report['rows'] as $row) {
            echo $row['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check the contents of your $reports variable, using var_dump function of php:

```
var_dump($reports);
```

It'll print something like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Then you can implement your loop looking at the actual data you have, in whichever way your jagged arrays are formed.